# Object creation in boost::singleton_pool

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost-pool

I am trying to use [boost::singleton_pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.singleton_pool) to create a large number of objects of a type 'Order' in a highly performance critical multithreaded application. Looking at the documentation, this is what I should be doing,

```
struct OrderTag{};
typedef boost::singleton_pool<OrderTag, sizeof(Order)> OrderPool;
```

boost::singleton_pool has a static member function malloc which returns pointer of the void*, but I need to create objects of the type Order in OrderPool by making calls to its constructor. Shall I be using [boost::pool_allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/pool_allocator.html) along with singleton_pool to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In short: no. boost::pool_allocator implementation itself uses boost::singleton_pool and provides interface like std::allocator so you can use it with STL containers (but not only STL and not only containers) like vector, list etc. The UserAllocator concept is not something like boost::pool_allocator but it's a thing that controls memory management at the lowest level. For example I wrote UserAllocator that allocates memory via mmap() function and not uses heap at all.

So to create objects of a type 'Order' you should use [boost::pool_allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/pool_allocator.html) or [boost::fast_pool_allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html). In your case it is not necessary to use boost::singleton_pool directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `singleton_pool` with placement `new` like this:

```
Order* p = new (OrderPool.malloc()) Order(/* add ctor parameters if any*/);
```

or use `boost::object_pool<Order>`